# How to use a Vue component library in browser?

Tags: vue.js

I have a Vue component [library](https://github.com/dgknca/vue-multi-split-pane). I built for browser via rollup. But I can't use in browser with CDN. What am I doing wrong? I've tried with `<script type="module">` and a lot of other things. Here is an example:

```html
<div id="app">
  <MultiSplitPane split="horizontal" height="400px" width="1000px">
    <Pane>
      <template v-slot:content>
        Content 1
      </template>
    </Pane>
    <Pane>
      <template v-slot:content>
        Content 2
      </template>
    </Pane>
    <Pane>
      <template v-slot:content>
        Content 3
      </template>
    </Pane>
  </MultiSplitPane>
</div>


<script type="module">
  import Vue from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.12/dist/vue.esm.browser.js'; 
  import { MultiSplitPane, Pane } from 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dgknca/vue-multi-split-pane/master/dist/vue-multi-split-pane.esm.js'; 
  
new Vue({ 
  el: '#app', 
  components: { MultiSplitPane, Pane } 
})
</script>
```

Also tried this

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app'
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.12/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dgknca/vue-multi-split-pane/master/dist/vue-multi-split-pane.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <MultiSplitPane
    split="horizontal"
    height="400px"
    width="1000px"
    resizerWidth="30px"
    classes="v-pane-custom">
    <Pane>
      <template v-slot:resizer>
        resizer slot
      </template>
      <template v-slot:content>
        Content 1
      </template>
    </Pane>
    <Pane>
      <template v-slot:content>
        Content 2
      </template>
    </Pane>
    <Pane>
      <template v-slot:content>
        Content 3
      </template>
    </Pane>
  </MultiSplitPane>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you mean Vue web components?

Comment: @Naren I guess. I'm not sure. Can you create an example with my library? Also you can send pull request if you want.

Comment: @usafder I want to use in browser with CDN. Not in a vue project with nodejs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bundle my component with rollup and found the correct way to define component. This works like I want.

```js
Vue.component('MultiSplitPane', VueMultiSplitPane.MultiSplitPane)
Vue.component('Pane', VueMultiSplitPane.Pane)

new Vue({
  el: '#app'
})
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Fira+Code&display=swap');
body {
  font-family: 'Fira Code', monospace;
  background: #d8d1d9;
}

.v-pane-custom .v-pane .content {
  background: #fff;
}

.v-pane-custom .content .innerContent {
  padding: 20px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

.paneNested>.content>.innerContent {
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <multi-split-pane split="horizontal" height="400px" width="1000px" resizerWidth="30px" classes="v-pane-custom">
    <Pane>
      <template v-slot:content>
        Content 1
      </template>
    </Pane>
    <Pane>
      <template v-slot:content>
        Content 2
      </template>
    </Pane>
    <Pane>
      <template v-slot:content>
        Content 3
      </template>
    </Pane>
  </multi-split-pane>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.12/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-multi-split-pane@1.1.1/dist/vue-multi-split-pane.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use Bili to build your library:
https://github.com/egoist/bili

try with this configuration in `bili.config.js`:

```
const magicImporter = require('node-sass-magic-importer');

module.exports = {
  banner: true,
  output: {
    extractCSS: false,
  },
  plugins: {
    vue: {
      css: true
    },
    style: {
      preprocessOptions: {
        scss: {
          importer: magicImporter(),
        },
      },
    },
  }
};
```

and in your `package.json`:

```
    "build": "vue-cli-service build --target lib --inline-vue src/index.js"
```

After this you can bundle your library with `npm run build` and you will have bundled js / css files in your `dist/` directory, if you load that JS and CSS in your browser in a HTML file you can use component in any website.

Do not miss in your `index.js` to mount your component to an element, like this:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import MyComponent from "./MyComponent.vue";

new Vue({
    el: '#my-component',
    render: h => h(MyComponent)
  })
```

Comment: it creates .umd.js and when I use it, it overrides my html and I can't use like I want

Comment: I tried it in my https://github.com/dgknca/vue-scroll-check component and I got this result  https://i.stack.imgur.com/UaEU3.png  https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHpWd.png

Comment: it is a very simple component, you can try on it. I pushed latest changes

Comment: I downloaded your dist and tried it, it almost ok. The problem should be that your main.js should be your entry point, rename index.js in your package.json to main.js and it will be bundled. 

Your demo.html should be the following, notes that you should import your script after your `div#app`: https://jsfiddle.net/goeyun5a/

I can see the result in my machine: https://ibb.co/cgvbWcm

Comment: I also created a pull request with the modifications

Comment: thanks for PR. I merged. but it just builds for production. still I can't use as a component. I would like to use it like this https://jsfiddle.net/mkx7rn9w/

Comment: You want to use in a single html file like this way as in your link?

Comment: Hey! Check my vue-multi-split-pane component. I added browser support finally. Rollup works fine. Thanks a lot for your efforts. I will give you the 100 reputations. Because I can't give to my own :) Pls don't forget upvoting my question.